# 404 function not found vs 404 data not found

Tags: http, standards

When someone calls https://example.com/schedule/5 and that schedule doesn't exist, I return a 404.

When someone calls https://example.com/scheduel/5, which is a mispelled address, I return a 404.

This isn't good because it makes data errors indistinguishable from code errors.

Is there a standard way to distinguish between the two? (Other than just dumping a stack trace in the body.)

Comment: Think of the URI as the "name" of the resource. From that point of view, both of those examples are a mis-naming of a resource and it makes sense to treat them the same.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26845858/13449712