# Appropriate HTTP Error Code for PUT Requests

Tags: rest, https, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have an application where a user can create several schedules from a list of events. Each item added to a schedule can be updated(or edited).

Assume `Schedule 1 contains Event 1 and Event 2` and `Schedule 2 contains Event 3 and Event 4`.

The endpoint to update an item in a schedule is `/api/{scheduleNumber}/{eventId}`

Now if the user sends a PUT request to the endpoint `/api/{1}/{3}`, with a properly formed body about the updated event, this is obviously wrong since Schedule 1 does not contain Event 3.

In this situation, is it appropriate to send `400 Bad Request`, assuming that the request has a valid syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that `404 Not Found` as response for [not found resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845631/is-it-correct-to-return-404-when-a-rest-resource-is-not-found) can be preferable approach and it is applicable in this case since no `Event 3` for `Schedule 1` exists.  And it would be better/more clear if combined with recommended ["use logical nesting on endpoints"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/02/best-practices-for-rest-api-design/#h-use-logical-nesting-on-endpoints) approach.